# .Net comparison to Objective C

Tags: .net, objective-c

We currently have .Net developers and the company is wanting our development team to get ready to start writing applications for iPhones and iPads.

Does anyone know of a good comparison (book, blog, article, anything...) that could help me move from .Net to Objective C?

I'm not specifically worried about the dirty details but I've grown up in a .Net world and all of my vocabulary is based on .Net and I'm needing to understand the equivalent in Objective C.

Comment: I would start from seeking the differences from memory model.

Comment: You may also consider: http://monotouch.net/

Comment: Have you considered hiring a consultant to mentor your team for their first iOS application? This may be worth more than the time spent ramping up on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two books I would recommend. "Beginning iPhone Development" and "The iPhone Developer's Cookbook". Have them go through and DO THE EXAMPLES. Each book takes a different approach, at lease one of which should "click" with your devs.